# How to handle the API call rate limit for Docusign in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

How to handle API call rate limit for Docusign in nodejs?I am getting error like "The maximum number of hourly API invocations has been exceeded ".

Comment: Can you show us the code? And a link to the API you are using would also be nice !

Answer (score 0):

So, you hit your QPH (queries per hour) limit, right?

Well, there are two things you can do to minize that:

- [Throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throttling_process_(computing))
- [Caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))

### Throttling

When an application has a query limit per period of time, throttling is often a common strategy used.

Throttling revolves around distributing your requests over a period of time. So for example, if you have a 500 limit of requests per hour, you can throttle your application to do 250 requests in the first 30 minutes, and 250 after.

This way you avoid hitting the limit. If you have more requests, then you save them for the next hour.

### Caching

Throttling is good because it gives you control over time. But sometimes, requests are similar, so similar in fact that you can just save the answer and use it for later.

Caching is also often used together with throttling, by saving the answers from old requests in your system, and re-using them, you effectively loose the need to make requests against the API, and you gain the ability to answer more user requests (provided you cached them before).

### Sum up

There  is no silver bullet to solve your problem. There is no simple line of code to do that. Instead, you have two methods that used together will minimize your problem and perhaps even eliminate it altogether if used correctly.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I copied  the source code from below url and see sample code in Usage section of below link.https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-Node-Client

Comment: did you add the login information correctly? Such as email, password, and so on?

Comment: I have no issues with authentication.  I am getting error like"The maximum number of hourly API invocations has been exceeded ".

Comment: complete your question with the info you have given me. more people will be able to understand your problem.

Comment: Docusign rest Api  has API Call Rate Limits and see below limitations for API.i)1,000 API calls per hour per account.ii)1 status request per unique envelope per 15 minutes.I want to know how to the  handle  API Call Rate Limits  in nodejs .